# Storing dictionary with numeric and string data

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary with some keys/values integers, others strings.

I am looking for a way to store this dictionary as a single file, with the following conditions:

1. Type sensitivity of keys and values are maintained.
2. I can view the mapping outside of Python.

I tried the following solutions, but with no success. Is there a way to do this, preferably without additional storage requirements / manipulation?

**Json**

Type sensitivity is maintained for values, but not keys:

```
import json

d = {'key1': 1, 2: '1'}

with open(loc2, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp, indent=4)

with open(loc2, 'r') as fp:
    d = json.load(fp)

{'2': '1', 'key1': 1}
```

**HDF5**

HDF5 dataset names must be strings, so this has the same problem as Json:

```
import h5py

f = h5py.File('file.h5', 'w', libver='latest')

for k, v in d.items():
    f.create_dataset(str(k), data=v)

f.close()
```

Comment: `json` keys needs to be string. If you are ok to write the file as string you can use something like `ast.literal_eval(str({'key1': 1, 2: '1'}))`.

Comment: @bro-grammer, But, since we can't write `"{'key1': 1, 2: '1'}"` via `json.dump`, does that mean we have to write a custom function to write the dictionary in the specific format? Totally valid solution, but seems messy..

Comment: I mean to say you can write the file using `str({'key1': 1, 2: '1'})`, then read it back using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Or you can subclass [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and [JSONDecoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder).

Comment: @bro-grammer, I understand you now. Never thought of the trivial solution. Feel free to post an answer (I can figure it out myself, but this could help others).

Comment: Could you use `csv`? `csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)`

Comment: You can write `writerow(["7", 7])`, and it will be read as `"7" 7.0`

Comment: If you need to conserve the types, you could go with XML.

Comment: @uwain12345, I haven't much experience with XML, will this require writing a schema and storing this separately (or together with) the data? If so, I feel this might be overkill for my use case.

Comment: @jpp: no, you don't need a schema, although it certainly helps. At its simplest, XML isn't really any more complcated than JSON.

Comment: If outside of Python means C++/Java maybe Pickling and using http://www.picklingtools.com/documentation is worth a try? (I haven't used it myself yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). Install `pip install pyyaml`.

```
import yaml

data = {
    'key1': 1,
    1: 2
}

with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Output file:

```
1: 2  
key1: 1
```

Reading the file:

```
with open("data.yml", 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.load(stream)
    print data[1] # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the file as string

```
>>> file = open('file.txt', 'w')
>>> file.write(str({'key1': 1, 2: '1'}))
```

Then read is back using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(file.read())
>>> {'key1': 1, 2: '1'}
```